Trying to scrub data from a website using javascript using Selenium
I want to be able to scrub a portion of data from a website, it has parameters such as gas day, cycle, and has a button in which to update the data provided. The data I want to scrub is from the data range 01/01/2024 through 05/13/2024.You have to use the "update" button if you want to access the next day. The cycle option I'd like to use is Final. After scrubbing the data, I'd like it all to be stored in an excel file.
The site: https://twtransfer.energytransfer.com/ipost/TW/main/index
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

 # Function to format date string
 def format_date(date_str):
     return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

 # Initialize Excel workbook and worksheet
 wb = Workbook()
 ws = wb.active
 ws.append(["Loc Name", "Gas Date", "Cycle", "OPC Capacity", "Sched QTY", "Qty Avail", "Loc Purp Desc"])

 # Initialize WebDriver
 chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\natha\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path) 

 try:
# Open the Operational Capacity page directly
driver.get("https://twtransfer.energytransfer.com/ipost/TW/main/index?page=OP&sidebar=opr")

# Wait for page to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dateRangeStart")))

# Set date range
start_date = format_date("01/01/2024")
end_date = format_date("05/13/2024")
current_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
while current_date <= datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d'):
    current_date_str = current_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "dateRangeStart").clear()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "dateRangeStart").send_keys(current_date_str)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "dateRangeEnd").clear()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "dateRangeEnd").send_keys(current_date_str)

    # Select cycle "Final"
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "cycle").send_keys("Final")

    # Click on the "Update" button
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "update").click()

    # Wait for data to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='grid']/tbody/tr")))

    # Extract data
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='grid']/tbody/tr")
    for row in rows:
        data = [cell.text for cell in row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")]
        ws.append(data)

    # Move to the next date
    current_date += timedelta(days=1)

# Save Excel workbook
wb.save("operational_capacity.xlsx")

 finally:
     # Close the WebDriver
     driver.quit()


I'm using chromium with selenium to try to scrub the website, however, I'm running into this error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\natha\Downloads\datascrub.py", line 19, in <module>
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

I don't know how to address this error especially since selenium is updated to 4.20.0.

As long as you're using the latest (or one of the latest) version of Selenium, you don't need to specify executable_path. Define your driver as explained in the official documentation.
